# set `action` attribute to a dynamically evaluated string

Tags: jsf, attributes, components, action, facelets

I need to set the action for a commandLink dynamically.

```
<ice:repeat value="#{mLeft.links}" var="xxx">
    <cvu:leftLink value="#{xxx.value}" action="#{xxx.action}" />
</ice:repeat>
```

My custom tag:

```
// old
<ui:composition>
    <ice:commandLink immediate="#{immediate}">
        <f:attribute name="action" value="#{action}" />
        <f:attribute name="actionListener" value="#{actionListener}" />
        <f:attribute name="value" value="#{value}" />
    </ice:commandLink>
</ui:composition>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. 
 In the past I solved a similar problem using Reflection. Isn't there a simpler solution ? 
 I'm using Facelets and JSF 2.0.

EDIT:

Ok. I changed the UI component to JSF 2.0 composite component, but I still can't manage to make it work. It works only if I call the custom component with a method, and it's re-targeted  to the link in my custom component. 
What I want is to be able to generate a list of links each one calling a method I give as **String** !
about `<cc:actionSource` I saw that it's used just for `<f:actionListener for="xxx" binding="" />`
Please Help.

```
// new one
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="action" required="true" targets="actiune" />
    <cc:attribute name="immediate" required="false" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <cc:actionSource name="ok" targets="actiune" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <ice:graphicImage value="/images/pucemenu.gif" alt="right"
        style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 13px;" />
    <ice:commandLink id="actiune" immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
    </ice:commandLink>
</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: Are you using composite components? If so you can use <composition:actionSource /> tag inside your composition's interface.

Comment: i'm not using composite components from JSF 2.0, i'm creating a custom component from Facelets. But I can switch to composite components from JSF 2.0 if it works. Can you show me an example ? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So there's no such thing supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

*Either* pass the bean around as well:

```xml
<ice:repeat value="#{mLeft.links}" var="xxx">
    <cvu:leftLink bean="#{xxx}" value="value" action="action" />
</ice:repeat>
```

with

```xml
<ui:composition>
    <ice:commandLink value="#{bean[value]}" action="#{bean[action]}" />
        ...
</ui:composition>
```

If you use a fixed value property and action method name, you could even omit them altogether and pass alone the bean:

```xml
<ice:repeat value="#{mLeft.links}" var="xxx">
    <cvu:leftLink bean="#{xxx}" />
</ice:repeat>
```

with

```xml
<ui:composition>
    <ice:commandLink value="#{bean.value}" action="#{bean.action}" />
        ...
</ui:composition>
```

---

*Or*, use a composite component wherein you define the action as `<cc:attribute method-signature>`):

```xml
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="action" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />
    ...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <ice:commandLink value="#{cc.attrs.value}" action="#{cc.attrs.action}" />
    ...
</cc:implementaiion>
```